# having problems with PDOstatement not containing what should be in there

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

below is the search function i have created and as far as i can tell i have not done anything with it incorrectly but i am returning no results from the search. i know for example str is 'evil' and when i replace :str with '%evil%' i get the expected results so why is it not working when i use the bindValue

```
function get_items($str) {
try{
    $db = db_open();
    $sql = "select jobs.* from jobs, employers where employers.employer = jobs.employer ";
    if ($str) {
      $sql .= "AND jobs.title LIKE :str ";
    }
    $sql .=  "order by id";
    $str = trim($str);
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':str', '$' . $str . '$');
    $statement->execute();
    echo($str);    
    $items = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $items;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
}
```

edit: would appear im rather tired and mixed up what symbols i was using

Comment: Why are you surrounding `str` with `$` characters and not `%`s?

Comment: thankyou for seeing what i couldnt after spending the weekend on this project -_- i feel silly now

Comment: Once you stare at a block of code for long enough, you become completely blind to its mistakes (see, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are surrounding your `str` with `$` characters instead of `%` characters. Instead of:

```
$statement->bindValue(':str', '$' . $str . '$');
```

You should have:

```
$statement->bindValue(':str', '%' . $str . '%');
```